# Terraform two vars on one loop

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a policy to give access to an x number of glue databases to a role, because there are more than 40 roles each one having access to different databases is not an option to create the policy one by one.

It is also not possible to separate the permissions by creating two statements one for tables and another one for databases as the role has 10 policies and because some of the roles have access to a lot of databases it reaches the maximum number of characters of the policy.

```
var.glue_database = ["databaseone", "databasetwo", "databasethree"]

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy_glue" {
    statement {
    actions = [
        "glue:Get*",
        "glue:Create*",
        "glue:Update*"
    ]
    effect = "Allow"
    resources = [
    for x in var.glue_databases : [
       formatlist("arn:aws:glue:${var.region}:${var.account}:database/%s", "${x}"), 
       formatlist("arn:aws:glue:${var.region}:${var.account}:table/%s/*", "${x}")
    ]
    ]
}
```

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type var glue_database is a list of strings with 3 elements.
```

I have also tried to convert it to a map:

```
locals{
glue_db = formatlist("arn:aws:glue:${var.region}:${var.account}:database/%s", "$var.glue_database}")
glue_table = formatlist("arn:aws:glue:${var.region}:${var.account}:table/%s/*", "$var.glue_database}")

database = [ for value in local.glue_db : { value = value } ]
table = [ for value in local.glue_table : { value = value } ]

glue_var = [ for k, v in zipmap (local.database-value[*], local.table.value[*]): {} ]
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy_glue" {
statement {
    actions = [
        "glue:Get*",
        "glue:Create*",
        "glue:Update*"
    ]
    effect = "Allow"
    resources = [
    for x in local.glue_var : join(",", x.key, x.value) 
    ]
}
```

```
Error: Unsupported attribute Can´t access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string)
```

What I am trying to get this:

```
var.glue_database = ["databaseone", "databasetwo", "databasethree"]

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy_glue" {
    statement {
    actions = [
        "glue:Get*",
        "glue:Create*",
        "glue:Update*"
    ]
    effect = "Allow"
    resources = [
       "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:12345678:database/databaseone",
       "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:12345678:table/databaseone/*",
       "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:12345678:database/databasetwo",
       "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:12345678:table/databasetwo/*",
       "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:12345678:database/databasethree",
       "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:12345678:table/databasethree/*",
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please show what your `var.glue_database` variable looks like, and what the actual errors you receive are (the whole error messages).

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to build in the first code example? What you have will produce a list of lists of lists for the `resources` field; I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: i am trying to make a policy on which on one unique statement i have all databases from the var glue_database with the permissions for databases and tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `resources` field expects a list of resource ARNs. The code you have shown will produce a list of lists of lists of ARNS, something like

```
resources = [
  [
    [
      "...database/db1"
    ]
    [
      "...table/db1"
    ]
  ]
  [
    [
      "...database/db2"
    ]
    [
      "...table/db2"
    ]
  ]
]
```

To produce the list that I think you're trying to make, you'll instead want to use code like

```
resources = flatten([
  formatlist("arn:aws:glue:${var.region}:${var.account}:database/%s", var.glue_databases), 
  formatlist("arn:aws:glue:${var.region}:${var.account}:table/%s/*", var.glue_databases)
])
```

[`formatlist`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/formatlist) takes a list (as its 2nd parameter) and produces another list, so each of those can just take the `glue_databases` directly, rather than doing it in a `for` loop. Then we can [`flatten`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten) those two lists into a single one, and the job is done.